# How to merged vertically in centre of the table

Tags: latex

I would like to center the vertically merged values. I also have a error named Undefined control sequence. When i compile the code, it shows me 4 and * . How to remove it? Can you please help me to solve this error.

[image: 1]

I tried to solve this error but i could not able to solve it. I am using this code.

Comment: Can you please show your code? Are you loading the `multirow` package?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how you built the table because you haven't shared a single line of code, nor have you shown a log. None of us can comment on the error you report. On this site, you are supposed to provide the full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Anyway, using just a standard environment `tabular` and the `\multirow` (defined in the package `multirow`) to merge cells, you can achieve any alignment you need: left, centred, right, top, middle and bottom:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \centering
  \caption{Caption}\label{tab:1}\vspace{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Head 1} & \textbf{Head 2} & \textbf{Head 3} \\
    \hline
    1 & \multirow[t]{3}*{Centred} & \multirow[t]{3}*{Right} \\
    2 & & \\
    3 & & \\
    \hline
    \multirow{3}*{Left} & 4 & \multirow{3}*{Right} \\
                    & 5 & \\
                    & 6 & \\ 
    \hline
    \multirow[b]{3}*{Left} & \multirow[b]{3}*{Centred} & 7 \\
                    & & 8 \\
                    & & 9 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]